# Total value based on skills is not printing correctly

Tags: java, inheritance

I am doing a basic JAVA program where I am displaying a total value based on the skills. FOr example- if a student has Python and ML then the total value shoud be 5 but if he/she is a master's student then total value should be 3+2+5. I have a data.csv file like below-

Data.csv

```
Tom,Hans, MS, Python, ML
Sam, Daniel, Python
```

I have the below method in parent and child class-

```
Parent class-

public int skillValue() {
  int skill = 0;
  
  if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Python")) {
    skill = skill + 3;
  } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("ML")) {
    skill = skill + 2;
  } else {
    skill = skill + 1;
  }
  return skill;
}

Child Class-

public int skillValue() {
   super.skillValue();
       
   int skill = 0;
   if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Masters")) {
      skill = skill + 5;
   } 
   return skill;
}
```

I am calling super() in my child class as the if else are same with just additional condition for MS student. I would like to know if I am doing this correctly as my skill values are not printing correctly. Thank you.

Comment: examine the first two lines of the method in the subclass

Comment: My parent is also not adding the values correctly. I am not sure what I am missing here. I tried replacing int skill = super.skillValue() in my subclass.

Comment: Please, provide output and code, where skillValue is called.

Comment: Every time that you say `int skill`, you are creating a _new, distinct_ variable called `skill`.

Answer (score 3):

You ignore return value of `super.skillValue()` call in child class. Replace

```
int skill = 0;
```

with

```
int skill = super.skillValue();
```